# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.home.Model.Order1

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order");

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Order1> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Order1>()
            .setQuery(reference.child(CurrentUser).child("Items").child("1553778276400"), Order1.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order1, OrderDeatilsViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order1, OrderDeatilsViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderDeatilsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Order1 model) {

            holder.proname.setText(model.getPname());
            holder.proquantity.setText(model.getQuantity());
            holder.proprice.setText(model.getPrice());
            holder.prototal.setText(model.getTootlamount());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OrderDeatilsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.orderdetailslayout, parent  ,false);
            OrderDeatilsViewHolder holder = new OrderDeatilsViewHolder(view);
            return  holder;
        }

    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();[enter image description here][1]
```

I try to get data but it show error like "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.home.Model.Order1"

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderDeatilsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.proname.setText(model.get(position).getPname());
        holder.proquantity.setText(model.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.proprice.setText(model.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.prototal.setText(model.get(position).getTootlamount());
        Picasso.get().load(model.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
    }
```